# img link makes whole bootstrap div clickable

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a div with an image. This image has an `<a>` tag around it.

Now it should only make the image clickable, but instead it makes the whole div clickable and the H4 that comes next to the image is pushed down below the div. The `<a>` takes the width of the whole div.

I'm using bootstrap col in the div class.

How can i fix this? I tried giving the `<a>` a width but that doesn't work...

Thanks in advance!

```
<header>
    <div class="image col-sm-8">
        <a href="home.php"><img class="img-responsive" src="Images/pc4u.png" style="height: 100px; width: 175px;"></a>
        <h4>PC4U voor al uw computers, onderdelen en software!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="userInformationAndShoppingCart col-sm-4">
        <h4>Middle</h4>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Do you maybe have a jsfiddle/codepen/etc. where we can see this behaviour in action? With just the code here it's hard to reproduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<H>` tags by default takes 100% width also if you want to show `img` and `h4` side by side then use `disply:inline-block` as shown below :

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <a href="home.php"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/30/Java_programming_language_logo.svg" style="height: 100px; width: 175px;display:inline-block"></a>
        <h4 style="display:inline-block">PC4U voor al uw computers, onderdelen en software!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="userInformationAndShoppingCart col-sm-4">
        <h4>Middle</h4>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
    <div class="image col-sm-8">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
         <a href="home.php"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/powr/defaults/image-slider2.jpg" style="height: 100px; width: 175px;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
         <h4>PC4U voor al uw computers, onderdelen en software!</h4>
        </div>
       
    </div>
    <div class="userInformationAndShoppingCart col-sm-4">
        <h4>Middle</h4>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **width:100%;** your image

```css
.image{
background:red;
}
img{
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="image col-sm-8">
        <a href="home.php"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg" style=""></a>
        <h4>PC4U voor al uw computers, onderdelen en software!</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="userInformationAndShoppingCart col-sm-4">
        <h4>Middle</h4>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

use style="display:inline" inside <a> tag, works in bootstrap-4

```html
<div class="col-sm-8">
        <a style="display:inline-block;" href="home.php"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/30/Java_programming_language_logo.svg"></a>
        <h4>PC4U voor al uw computers, onderdelen en software!</h4>
    </div>
```